# Explicit bounds on the multinomial coefficient ${n\choose \vec{n}}$ when $\vec{n}$ is almost proportional to some given weight vector?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, estimation, upper-lower-bounds, multinomial-coefficients

Assume $n\geq t$ are positive integers and fix some arbitrary nonnegative *weight* vector $\vec\lambda = (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_t)$ where $\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_t = 1$.  Suppose further that $\vec{n} = (n_1,\dots,n_t)$ is a weak composition of $n$ into $t$ parts which is *nearly proportional to $\vec\lambda$* in the sense that $\|\vec{n}-n\vec\lambda\|_\infty<1$.  In other words, $\vec n$ is obtained by rounding the vector $n\vec\lambda$ to an integer vector whose entries also sum to $n$.

Using Robbins' [version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) of Stirling's approximation which states that
$$
e^{ 1/(12n+1) }\leq \dfrac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi\,n}\cdot (n/e)^n} \leq e^{1/(12n)}, 
$$
it follows that 
$$
\exp\left\{ \dfrac{1}{12n+1} - \sum_{i=1}^t\dfrac{1}{12n_i}\right\}
\leq
\dfrac{{n\choose \vec n}}
{\sqrt{ \dfrac{n}{(2\pi)^{t-1}n_1\cdots n_t} } \cdot 
\dfrac{n^n}{n_1^{n_1}\cdots n_t^{n_t}}
}
\leq \exp\left\{ \dfrac{1}{12n} - \sum_{i=1}^t\dfrac{1}{12n_i+1}\right\}.  
$$
These upper and lower bounds only depend explicitly only on $n$ and $\vec{n}$.  With some extra work, they can be replaced with bounds which depend only on $n$ and $\vec\lambda$, and with some additional work, they can be made to depend only on $n$ and $t$.  However, we have not yet estimated $n_1^{n_1}\cdots n_t^{n_t}$.  Clearly it *should* be close to $(\lambda_1n)^{\lambda_1 n}\cdots (\lambda_tn)^{\lambda_tn} = (\lambda_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots \lambda_t^{\lambda_t})^n\cdot n^n$, but my best efforts have not yielded an improvement on the following (rough) estimate.  For convenience we write $(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_t) = \vec\varepsilon = \vec n - n\vec\lambda$ and abusively write $[a\,\dots\, b]$ to mean any number between $a$ and $b$: 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^t\dfrac{n_i^{n_i}}{(\lambda_in)^{\lambda_in}} = \prod_{i=1}^t \left(1+\dfrac{\varepsilon_i}{\lambda_in}  \right)^{\lambda_in}\cdot n_i^{\varepsilon_i}\approx \prod_{i=1}^t e^{\varepsilon_i}\cdot (\lambda_in+\varepsilon_i)^{\varepsilon_i} = \prod_{i=1}^t[1/n\, \dots\, n]^{|\varepsilon_i|} = [n^{-t}\, \dots \, n^t].
$$
Is there a way to replace these $n^t$ and $n^{-t}$ estimates with numbers much closer to $1$?  I do not mind if they depend on $n,\vec\lambda,t$.  Note that I am seeking global bounds for all $n$ and $t$ and $\vec\lambda$ and have explicitly avoided big/little-oh notation (except for the abusive $\approx$ at the end, which I hope to eliminate as well).

Feel free to avoid Robbins' estimate as well.  I just find that it does a nice job reducing to a cleaner problem.

**EDIT**: Technically it should be specified that we wish to explicitly estimate how close $n_1^{n_1+1/2}\cdots n_t^{n_t+1/2}$ is to $(\alpha_1n)^{\alpha_1n+1/2}\cdots (\alpha_tn)^{\alpha_tn+1/2}$.